# Docker generating SSL certs error

Tags: ssl, docker, lets-encrypt, docker-compose, certbot

I'm trying to generate certificates with the letsencrypt image and save them to a named volume but I'm having issues.  It's only generating the certificate for the top level domain, not any subdomains.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    ssl:
        container_name: ssl
        image: linuxserver/letsencrypt
        restart: unless-stopped
        network_mode: host
        environment:
         - TZ=America/New_York
         - PUID=0
         - PGID=0
         - EMAIL=email@gmail.com
         - URL=example.com
         - SUBDOMAINS=cloud,netdata
         - VALIDATION=http
        volumes:
        - "ssl:/etc/letsencrypt"
volumes:
    ssl:
```

Full log of container: https://pastebin.com/DHKNvywG

Comment: Can you check if the certificate appears here: https://crt.sh/

Comment: @jrtapsell they do but not in the docker volume.